# Mounting external sd-card on rooted Android 7.1 tablet fails, but only if partition not empty

Tags: sd-card, mount, ext4

Edit: I have tried mounting the sd-card with an empty ext4-partition, and it worked just fine, but after I ran `debootstrap` on the sd-card, the problem reappeared with identical symptoms.

---

I want to mount an ext4-formatted sd-card, but

`# mount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 mountpoint`

returns

`mount: mounting /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 on mountpoint/ failed: Invalid argument`

So far I have:

- made sure the sd-card itself is OK (mounts fine on my debian laptop)
- made sure the block device is the right one
- replaced `mount` with `busybox mount` , which is a different binary, but gives the same error

The mountpoint exists, and the kernel supports ext4. My device is a rooted Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 running a Lineage OS 14.1 ROM (Android 7.1), SELinux is set to permissive.

---

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does sdcard mount Android storage setting?

Run blkid command, see what say about partition.

Also what is mountpoint? I.E. /mnt/sd-ext

If you call mount like this

```
# mount -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 mountpoint
```

You have to be in same directory as mountpoint